# How can I exclude pieces of data in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R studio and having a little trouble. I am trying to output unique counties form a data set. So far I have

`sort(unique(x$Location) )`

`[1] Africa  Asia    Carlow  Cavan   Cork    Dublin  Europe  Galway`

`[9] Kildare Laois   Louth   Mayo    Meath`

`13 Levels: Africa Asia Carlow Cavan Cork Dublin Europe ... Meath`

I want that list but without "Africa", "Asia" and "Europe"
What function should I use to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would do this:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- x %>%
filter(Location != "Africa", Location != "Asia", Location != "Europe")

sort(unique(x$Location))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have factor variable you can use `levels` to get unique levels and then remove `c('Africa', 'Asia', 'Europe')` from it using `setdiff`.

```
lvls <- setdiff(levels(x$Location), c('Africa', 'Asia', 'Europe'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

(x %>%
  filter(!Location %in% c("Africa", "Asia", "Europe")) %>%
  pull(Location) %>%
  unique() ->
  locations)
```